# How to set multiple UILabels from array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, tags, uilabel

What I'm trying to do is to get today's weekday. From it I get the rest 6 weekdays, I put them into an array and then try to use this array to update 7 `UILabel`s. A short list of weekdays starting from today that is. My `UILabel`s are in a referencing outlet collection and I have set their tags from 0 to 6.

I have tried multiple different versions (originally without any array) of this and have managed to make this work on Playground, up to the point that I have the weekdays in the array but on the actual project, when I try to update the labels, it builds successfully but then crashes.

Edit: Crash comes after successful build. Error in Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1. Stops at the row super.viewDidLoad() apparently.

Edit2: made changes as suggested. Build succeeds and then crashes in the same style as in first Edit.

Any help is appreciated.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var label: [UILabel]!

    var rollingDay = NSDate()
    var array: [String]  = []

    func addDays() {
        var calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        var stringRolling = formatter.stringFromDate(rollingDay)

        for var x = 0; x<7; x++ {
            calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
            formatter = NSDateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
            stringRolling = formatter.stringFromDate(rollingDay)
            array.append(stringRolling)
            rollingDay = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, value: 1, toDate: rollingDay, options: nil)!
        }
    }
func updateLabels() {
    for (index, day) in enumerate(array) {
        let label : UILabel = self.view.viewWithTag(index) as! UILabel
        label.text = day as String
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    addDays()
    updateLabels()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to update your question with details about the crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have already used `array` to keep all the weekdays, now you just have to enumerate the array to set the labels as shown below:

```
for (index, day) in enumerate(array) {

    let label : UILabel = self.view.viewWithTag(index) as! UILabel
    label.text = day as String
}
```

Comment: Can you show your solution in the original code? My knowledge of Swift is very limited, I tried to integrate your solution with variable interesting errors. In my solution I append the weekdays to the array, using NSArray this doesn't seem to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Made the changes to the original code. Builds ok but crashes as in first Edit. Puzzling.

Comment: what are the elements in your array? on what does it crash and with what exception reason? please post tht here.

Comment: Array consist of weekdays that are provided by NSDate. Now I managed to get an actual error report, it says "Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x1996ff510) to 'UILabel' (0x199700e10)."

Comment: This is happening because there must be a `UIView` with tag 0 (because 0 is default tag value) in the subviews of `self.view`. That is why `self.view.viewWithTag(0)` will crash as it is not a `UILabel`. You cannot use 0 tag for any weekday. Try to add a constant number to all the weekday indices.

Comment: Yes, that was the error. UIView had a tag of 0 and was messing up the process. Thank you!!!